# Negative values returned by the intrinsic __mm_loadu_si128

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics

This is my code so far:

```
void main()
{
    unsigned char *test = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)* 16);        
    test[0] = 100;
    test[1] = 128;
    test[2] = 255;
    test[3] = 156;
    test[4] = 190;
    test[5] = 200;
    test[6] = 230;
    test[7] = 250;
    test[8] = 200;
    test[9] = 100;
    test[10] = 100;
    test[11] = 127;
    test[12] = 150;
    test[13] = 170;
    test[14] = 190;
    test[15] = 200;

    //__m256i sa = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    __m128i sa2 = _mm_setzero_si128();
    sa2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&test[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", sa2.m128i_i8[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test some SSE intrinsic function.
I used `__mm_loadu_si128();` to load an array that is of type `unsigned char`.
The expected result is

> { 100, 128,  .... , 190, 200}

However, I get the result

> {100, -128, -1, -100, -66, -56, -26, -6, -56, ... , -86, -66, -56}

Binary value of final result values is same value that I expected result.
I wonder why negative values are loaded by `_mm_loadu_si128`.
Please help me!

Comment: How about print them like `printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)sa2.m128i_i8[i]);`  . Also surprised you were able to put the value 300 into an `unsigned char`

Comment: Oh! I didn't revise code.... I checked printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)sa2.m128i_i8[i]). But real values of array doesn't change isn't it?

Comment: Should also point out if you are using MSVC then I'd probably do it this way `printf("%hhu\n", sa2.m128i_i8[i]);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) But I want correct value is loaded at __m128i sa2. Not just print correct value. :(

Comment: What makes you think `sa2` has the wrong values? It has the right ones, you just used `printf` incorrectly. `m128i_i8` is signed 8 bit value and `printf` promoted them to signed integers before printing. The alternative is to use `m128i_u8` which treats them as unsigned 8 bit values.

Comment: Oh! I understand! Thank you!! :-)